# Use to parameter inside of dynamic route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a product overview - this overview contains several products with several categories. I created a header to filter these categories by using router-outlet. This works.

Want I want to achieve:
Let's say the user is inside of category 'Tables', the path would look like this: `.../tables`. Now if the user clicks a table I want to open the respective product page.

I tried to do the following:

```
{path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: {breadcrump: 'Produkte'}, children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: ':category', component: ProductOverviewComponent},
  {path: ':category/:name', component: ProductPageComponent},
]},
```

And call the following path on route click:

```
routerLink="/products/{{product.category.toLowerCase()}}/{{product.name.toLowerCase()}}"
```

Anyways this doesn't work. Using the path will end nowhere, how so?

EDIT:
Additionally I realized, that trying to route to `routerLink="/"` (only when on the categories page) won't work as well - might be something with my whole routing then. Updated the question with the whole router set.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent},
  {path: 'request', component: RequestComponent},
  {path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: {breadcrump: 'Produkte'}, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: ':category', component: ProductOverviewComponent},
      {path: ':category/:name', component: ProductPageComponent},
    ]},
  {path: 'error404', component: NotFoundComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/error404'}
];
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem in this [**demo**](https://ng-run.com/edit/BUDQC6BoJIqWhboTs0KC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/products', product.category, product.name]"> Link </a>
```

I don't know if the `.toLowerCase()` will work in the HTML but you can try it. If it doesn't work, lowercase it in the TypeScript before it is painted in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks but the path still won't change. Additionally I realized, that trying to route to `routerLink="/"` (only when on the categories page) won't work as well - might be something with my whole routing then. Updated the question with the whole router set.

Comment: Try putting the first route as `{path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: Still smh won't allow me to navigate to any other route, I think there's a problem with the `products` route and its children.

Comment: Found it, your solution worked - just had to resolve some other error within the component!